# Error con move_uploaded_file en xampp

Tags: php, xampp

Estoy intentado subir una img a una carpeta pero me da error, no se si es culpa del xampp o cual puede ser el problema he mirado errores ya posteados pero no me ha funcionado ninguno o no lo he sabido aplicar :/

```
<?php 

        if( $_POST ){

            //ss
            extract( $_POST, EXTR_OVERWRITE );

            if  (!file_exists("fotos")){
                mkdir ( "fotos","0777");
            }

            $nombre = strtolower($nombre);

            $dirSubida = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/fotos/$nombre/";

            if  ( !file_exists ("fotos")){
                mkdir( $dirSubida, 0777);
            }

            $foto = $_FILES['foto'];
            $nombreFoto = $foto['name'];
            $nombreTmp = $foto{'tmp_name'};
            $rutaSubida = "{$dirSubida}profile.jpg";
            $extArchivo = preg_replace('/image\//', '', $foto['type']);

            if ($extArchivo == 'jpeg' || $extArchivo == 'png'){
                if ( move_uploaded_file ($nombreTmp, $rutaSubida)){
                    echo "<img class='img-responsive' src='$rutaSubida' alt=''>";
                }

            }

        }

        ?>
```

Este es el error:

> **Warning:** move_uploaded_file(C:/xampp/htdocs/fotos/qwe/profile.jpg): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\registrar.php on line 39
>
> **Warning:** move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php17A8.tmp' to 'C:/xampp/htdocs/fotos/qwe/profile.jpg'
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\registrar.php on line 39

Comment: Creo que hay un erro con las llaves {} en: `$nombreTmp = $foto{'tmp_name'};` deberia ser `$nombreTmp = $foto['tmp_name'];`

Comment: Lo he cambiado pero tampoco es eso...

Comment: Ya esta arreglado. He colocado mal la variable (esto me pasa por hacer ctrl+c ctrl+v) el 2 if he puesto "fotos" en vez de la ruta -.-